# Add minutes to Store Times

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code.

Here I'm trying to add 12 minutes to the time(Store Time), but this extra minutes were not adding to the time. Even the value in double also doesn't helped.

```
TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(getTotal.StoreTime.Hours, getTotal.StoreTime.Minutes, 00);
DateTime time = DateTime.Today.Add(timespan);
time.AddMinutes(12);
```

Can some one guide me?

Comment: [`AddMinutes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a _new_ `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign it to your "time" variable.

time = time.AddMinutes(12);

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime`'s in C# are immutable. This means, like `string`'s, their value cannot change. This means that when you execute a method, such as `AddMinutes`, it cannot change the value. Instead, it returns a new `DateTime` object. So, you must assign this new value to your variable:

```
time = time.AddMinutes(12);
```